# Access elements of an array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays

I'm using weatherapi to get forecast data and I want to access the hourly forecast and display the time and condition text for each hour object in a react component. The problem is, I just can't figure out how to get to them, I know this might seem pretty simple but I've tried.Check code snippet below[image]

```js
        <Box>
          {weather?.forecast.forecastday.hour.map((hour) => (
            <Slider {...settings}>
              <div key={hour.time}>(hour.temp_c)</div>
            </Slider>
          ))}
        </Box>
```

Comment: Please show us what you have tried and explain how/why that's not working.

Comment: and it's better to post actual code, not images. See [Why should I not upload images?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`forecastday` is also an array, so you either need to `find` which day you want to be iterating over, or map over that as well, which will give you an array (days) of arrays (hours)

if you're just interested in the first forecastday's data, you can select the first item in the forecastday array

```
         {weather?.forecast.forecastday[0]?.hour.map((hour) => (
            <Slider {...settings}>
              <div key={hour.time}>(hour.temp_c)</div>
            </Slider>
          ))}
```